# Using Quaternion to represent gyroscope angle in C#

Tags: c#, xna, orientation, quaternions, wiimote

I'm using the WiiM+ gyro to calculate rotation.

I integrate the rates of turn along the yaw, pitch and roll axes and store it in a vector called angleSum

So for each reading, angleSum(reading) represents the y, p and r rotations from the initial orientation.

I then use quaternions (which I'm totally unfamiliar with) to represent like this:

q = Quaternion.createfromyawPitchRoll(angleSum.yaw, angleSum.pitch, angleSum.roll*(-1))

But when I turn my wiimote 90 degrees in a direction and print out q.x, q.y and q.z for the turn, ALL readings are affected by the turn (they all show a 90 degree turn and back, although magnitude is smaller for two of them)

My question is very basic: how exactly do I use this quaternion structure to represent orientation? I need an absolute (or atleast relative) orientation in terms of yaw, pitch and roll.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A [quaternion](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Quaternion) is a four-dimensional construct loosely defined as an axis and a rotational component around the defined axis (usually represented as `{x, y, z, w}`). Having a look at [the method you've referenced,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463942.aspx) I'll assume you're supplying yaw, pitch, and roll in [radians](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Radian) instead of degrees. That'll remove the most common implementation mistake from the table.

Assuming your implementation is correct (and it seems to be), `q.x`, `q.y`, and `q.z` will all expectedly change with any rotation. Remember, you're defining a four-dimensional object; quaternions are *not* the same as [Euler angles.](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Euler_angles)

If you'd *like* to get a readout in more human-friendly Euler notation, consider converting your quaternion back into yaw, pitch, and roll. [Here's a discussion](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/4574/23763.aspx) for doing so in XNA.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But if I convert it back to Euler angles, then what's the purpose of creating the quaternion in the first place? I don't perform any operations on it (my angles are initially in degrees, which I convert to radian and use to create the quaternion)

Comment: My final goal is to display the orientation of the gyroscope in world coordinates (of yaw, pitch and roll) How would I use the quaternion to achieve that?